# How to track the first word before space in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

So basically i got a question , i want my string to start with X or Y or Z then an espace then a string
exemple

```
<hey>X String</hey>
```

so how to force it in the xsd file to make it like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a [restricted pattern](https://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/RestrictedPattern/) with an `xs:restriction` and an `xs:pattern` with a regex such as this:

<xs:element name="hey">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="(X|Y|Z)\s\w+"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>